# calculations on multiple selects dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

I am trying calculate the amount on change of select dropdown. I need each row calculation front of that row i.e. subtotal and all subtotal will be at bottom at "Total Amount"

I am getting the calculations for first row, but there is issues somewhere, i cannot findout properly. Please help me.

[image]

My code is

```js
  
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
 var bookIndex = 1;
    jQuery('#orderform')
        // Add button click handler
  
        .on('click', '.addButton', function() {
            bookIndex++;
   
            var $template = jQuery('#bookTemplate'),
                $clone    = $template
                                .clone()
                                .removeClass('hide')
                                .addClass('form-group')
                                .removeAttr('id')
                                .removeAttr('style')
        .attr('id', "row"+bookIndex)
                                .attr('data-index', bookIndex)
                                .insertBefore($template);
   jQuery("#row"+bookIndex+' .addprice span').addClass('item_price');
   jQuery("#row"+bookIndex+' .addprice input').addClass('itemprice');
   jQuery("#row"+bookIndex+' > div ').removeClass('addprice');

            
            // Add new fields
            // Note that we also pass the validator rules for new field as the third parameter
   
   var totalamount = 0;
    var price =0;
    jQuery('.dynamic-fields > .form-group').each(function () {
     price = jQuery("span.item_price").html();
     totalamount += parseFloat( price );
    });
    
    jQuery("#totalamount > span").html(totalamount);
    jQuery("#totalamount").attr('data-amount', totalamount);
           
        })

        // Remove button click handler
        .on('click', '.removeButton', function() {
            var $row  = jQuery(this).parents('.form-group'),
                index = $row.attr('data-book-index');

            // Remove fields
           

            // Remove element containing the fields
            $row.remove();
    var totalamount = 0;
    var price =0;
    jQuery('.dynamic-fields > .form-group').each(function () {
     price = jQuery("span.item_price").html(); 
     totalamount += parseFloat( price );
    });
    
    jQuery("#totalamount > span").html(totalamount);
    jQuery("#totalamount").attr('data-amount', totalamount);
   
        });
});



jQuery(document).ready(function(){
 var totalamount = 0;
 var price =0;
 jQuery('.dynamic-fields > .form-group').each(function () {
  price = jQuery("span.item_price").html();
  totalamount += parseFloat( price );
 });
    
 jQuery("#totalamount > span").html(totalamount);
 jQuery("#totalamount").attr('data-amount', totalamount);
 
})

jQuery(".dynamic-fields").each(function() {
  var tpy = parseInt(jQuery(".service_type option:selected").val());
  var clths = parseInt( jQuery(".cloths option:selected").val() );
  var quantity = parseInt( jQuery(".quantity option:selected").val() );
  
  var total;
  total= tpy + clths * quantity; 
  jQuery("span.item_price").html(total);
  jQuery("input.itemprice").attr('value', total);
});

jQuery(document).on("change", '.dynamic-fields > div.form-group select', function() {
    var total = 0; 
 var id  = jQuery(this).parent().parent().attr('id');
 var index  = jQuery(this).parent().parent().attr('data-index');
 id = '#'+id+' '; //alert(id); //alert(index);
    //jQuery('.form-group').each(function () {
  
        var tpy   = jQuery(id+'.service_type option:selected').val();
  var clths   = jQuery(id+'.cloths option:selected').val();
  var quantity  = jQuery(id+'.quantity option:selected').val();
  
  total= ( parseInt(tpy) + parseInt(clths) ) * parseInt(quantity); 
  jQuery(id+".item_price").html(total);
 jQuery(id+".itemprice").attr('value', total);
    //});
 var totalamount = 0;
 var price =0;
 jQuery('.accept-checkbox.dynamic-fields > div.form-group').each(function () {
  price = jQuery("span.item_price").html(); 
  totalamount += parseFloat( price );
 });
    
 jQuery("#totalamount > span").html(totalamount);
 jQuery("#totalamount").attr('data-amount', totalamount);
 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form name="neworder" action="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" method="post" id="orderform"> 
<div class="accept-checkbox dynamic-fields">
   
    <div class="form-group" id="row1" data-index="1">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
     <select class="service_type" name="service_type[]">
      <option value="20">Iron</option>
      <option value="30">Wash</option>
      <option value="40">Wash &amp; Iron</option>
      <option value="50">Dryclean</option>
     </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
     <select class="cloths" name="cloths[]">
      <option value="10">Shirt</option>
      <option value="20">Tshirt</option>
      <option value="30">Kurta</option>
      <option value="40">Jeans</option>
      <option value="50">Trouser</option>
      <option value="60">Trouser</option>
     </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
     <select class="quantity" name="quantity[]">
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="3">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
      <option value="6">6</option>
     </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
     <span class="item_price">30</span>
     <input type="hidden" class="itemprice" value="00"/> 
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">
     <button class="btn btn-default addButton" type="button"><i class="fa fa-plus">+</i></button>
    </div>
   </div>

   <!-- The template for adding new field -->
   
   <div id="bookTemplate" class=" hide" style="display: none;">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
     <select class="service_type" name="service_type[]">
      <option value="20">Iron</option>
      <option value="30">Wash</option>
      <option value="40">Wash &amp; Iron</option>
      <option value="50">Dryclean</option>
     </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
     <select class="cloths" name="cloths[]"> 
      <option value="10">Shirt</option>
      <option value="20">Tshirt</option>
      <option value="30">Kurta</option>
      <option value="40">Jeans</option>
      <option value="50">Trouser</option>
      <option value="60">Trouser</option>
     </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
     <select class="quantity" name="quantity[]">
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="3">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
      <option value="6">6</option>
     </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 addprice">
     <span >30</span>
     <input type="hidden" value="00"/> 
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-1">
     <button class="btn btn-default removeButton" type="button"><i class="fa fa-minus"> - </i></button>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row"> 
    <div class="col-md-5 pull-right">
     <span><strong>Total Amount : </strong></span><span id="totalamount"> <span>00.00</span>/- </span>
    </div>
   </div>
  </form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The added elements do not have an event handler.

To write one event handler for current and future elements, replace this:

```
jQuery('.dynamic-fields > div.form-group select').on("change", function () {
```

With:

```
jQuery(document).on("change", '.dynamic-fields > div.form-group select', function() {
```

Note that you still have many issues with your code. You should better keep your quantities, prices, etc.. (also) in variables, and not re-read them every time from html attributes.

For instance these lines are now wrong:

```
    jQuery(".item_price").html(total);
    jQuery("input.itemprice").attr('value', total);
```

You intended this:

```
    jQuery(id+".item_price").html(total);
    jQuery(id+".itemprice").attr('value', total);
```

... and there are more issues like that, but if I were you, I would refactor this code to rely less on the html attributes for calculating the total.

Comment: Really thanks, trincot, 
it works for every row, but getting problem in Final total after adding new row. it it adding first row price every time. Please help me out from that.

Comment: Like I said, you need to rewrite a lot of your code. If you need help with specific issues, you should post a new question specifically about that. This comments section is not suitable for dealing with follow-up questions. If you post a new question with your current code and exact problem statement, I will be glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

change the line

```
jQuery('.dynamic-fields > div.form-group select').on("change", function() { ...
```

to

```
jQuery(document).on("change", '.dynamic-fields > div.form-group select', function() { ...
```

because the EventListener `change` is bind once to the elements that are at the time in DOM the code is executed with selector `.dynamic-fields > div.form-group select`.
Now the EventListener is set to the document und the function is executed when event.target is `.dynamic-fields > div.form-group select`.